# Calculating fund alpha using Fama-French 3 factor model?

Tags: regression, factor-models, fama-french, excel, mutual-fund

My dissertation requires me to evaluate fund performance, and for that I need to find the alpha for each fund. I have 173 funds total. I have all the inputs for the 3-factor model, and I realise running a regression and finding the intercept is the fund's alpha - however, is there a faster way of doing this due to the number of funds I have? I do not want to run a regression for every single fund, so is there a quicker way of doing this in Excel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your math/programming background? Been exposed to matrices and [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra)? Done anything in R? MATLAB? or Python?

Comment: I have limited math and programming background (more qualitative work) so I wouldn't know how to use Matlab etc. Is there a way I could calculate the alphas in excel?

Answer (score 4):

In the long run, you'd probably be better off learning a real programming language like Python, R, or MATLAB. While you can do this in Excel using `mmult`, `transpose`, and `minverse`, it's rather horrible.

In any case, you should know about the mathematical idea of a [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)), matrix multiplication, and the inverse of a matrix. (Multiplying by the inverse of a matrix is solving a linear system.)

In my notation, capital letters (eg. A) will be matrices, bold letters (eg. $\mathbf{b}$) will denote column vectors, and lower case letters will denote [scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)) (i.e. regular numbers). $A_{ij}$ will refer to the $i$th row of column $j$ of matrix $A$.

#### The brief recipe:

- Let $R$ be a $n$ by $k$ matrix of returns where we have $n$ time periods and $k$ assets.
- An excess return is a return in excess of the risk free rate. First you need to compute a matrix $Y$ of excess returns. Let $r^f_t$ denote the risk free rate at time $t$. The excess return of asset $i$ at time $t$ is the return minus the risk free rate:
  $$ Y_{ti} = R_{ti} - r^f_t$$
- You also need a $n$ by $3$ matrix $F$ of the three Fama-French factors. (Note these are already zero cost portfolios since the risk free rate or other portfolio return has been sbutracted off.) Form a matrix $X$ by pre-appending a column of 1s.
  $$ X = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{1} & F \end{bmatrix}$$

Then your solution to running those 173 regressions is given by:
$$ \hat{B} = (X'X)^{-1} X'Y$$
The alphas will be in the first row of $\hat{B}$. The residuals are given by:
$$ \hat{U} = Y - X \hat{B}$$
For each column of $\hat{U}$, calculate estimate of the variance of the error terms as:

$$ \hat{\sigma}^2_i = \frac{1}{n - k - 1} \sum_{t=1}^n \hat{U}_{ti}^2 $$

Let $\hat{\mathbf{d}} = \operatorname{diag}((X'X)^{-1})$ be the diagonal elements of $(X'X)^{-1}$. Your standard error for the alpha estimate for security $i$ would be:

$$ \hat{s}_{i1} = \sqrt{\hat{\sigma}^2_i \hat{d}_1}$$
Standard error for estimate of beta would be (assuming the market excess return is in the 2nd column of X):
$$ \hat{s}_{i2} = \sqrt{\hat{\sigma}^2_i \hat{d}_2}$$

Comment: BTW, you can do better than this in terms of sensible standard-errors. You really should do heteroskedasticity robust standard-errors (rather than the homoskedastic assuming standard-errors here) but this recipe is complicate enough already.